# position of "hingegen", position one?

Tags: word-order, adverb, conjunction

In canoonet "**hingegen**" is considered a conjunctional adverbs with position one! ([Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Klasse/Konjunktional.html))

But examples that dwds (https://www.dwds.de/wb/hingegen) gives "hingegen" is not in the position one, even the verb comes in position 3, how?

- am Wochenende schien die Sonne, heute hingegen regnet es
- Diebstähle kommen noch vor, Mordfälle sind hingegen selten geworden
- er ist sparsam, sie hingegen verschwendet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your "position 1" terminology (which I only know as a concept used to describe the position of verbs). At any rate, and as you may suspect based on the DWDS examples, the adverbial connector *hingegen* is not subject to any of the positional limitations frequently imposed on connectors (*Pasch et al.*, Handbuch der deutschen Konnektoren, vol. 1, 2003, p. 712), meaning that it can, potentially, fill the prefield (e.g.: *Hingegen vertrat Herr Müller die Position, dass ...*), the position right after the first sentence constituent (Nacherstposition, literally: post-first position) (e.g.: *Er ist sparsam, sie hingegen verschwendet ihr Geld.*) as well as the midfield (e.g.: *Diebstähle kommen noch vor, Mordfälle sind hingegen selten geworden.*). In addition, *hingegen*, sporadically, fills the pre-prefield (Nullposition) (e.g.: *Ich bin durchaus kritisch beim Einkaufen, wenn es um kleine Kinder geht. Hingegen: Was soll an Nutella schlecht sein?*).

As a general matter, it appears that contrastive-comparative adverbial connectors have a certain affinity for the post-first position. See, *Breindl et al.*, Handbuch der deutschen Konnektoren, vol. 2,1, 2014, p. 542. In the case of *hingegen*, it seems to be a close call, however. *Breindl et al.* observe that in their (admittedly small) sample of 100 randomly selected occurrences of the connector, in 54 cases it filled the post-first position, in 45 cases the midfield, and in only one case the prefield. *Id.*, at 543.

If you have similar questions in the future and are looking for a reliable resource, I commend you to consult the dictionary of connectors by the *Institut für deutsche Sprache* (IDS). You can find it at https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/konnektoren; as an example, the entry for *hingegen* can be found at https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/konnektoren/407057.

Answer (score 1):

In the cases where the verb seems to be at position 3 *hingegen* is actually an attribute of the first part of the sentence.

> Am Wochenende schien die Sonne, heute hingegen regnet es.

Here *hingegen* belongs to *heute*, so the first part of the sentence is *heute hingegen*.

> Er ist sparsam, sie hingegen verschwendet.

Here *hingegen* belongs to *sie*, so the first part of the sentence is *sie hingegen*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take that word classification too seriously. German makes no sharp distinction between conjunctions and adverbs. That's why run-on-sentences with some coordinating *adverb-conjunctions* sprinkled all over it are best practice in German.

> **Er** *hingegen* riss *jeweils* alles an sich, was an Arbeit anlag.
>
> **Er** riss *hingegen jeweils* alles an sich, was an Arbeit anlag.
>
> **Hingegen** riss er *jeweils* alles an sich, was an Arbeit anlag.
>
> **Hingegen** riss er alles *jeweils* an sich, was an Arbeit anlag.
>
> **Jeweils** riss er *hingegen* alles an sich, was an Arbeit anlag.

etc etc. Word order in these cases is dominated by emphasis.